# Prometheus blackbox exporter failing https but not http

Tags: https, prometheus, http2, black-box-testing, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have the below config for a module. The only thing this module is used for is a website that returns a 403. When using http it works fine when using https it fails.

```
  proxy_http_4xx:
    prober: http
    timeout: 5s
    http:
      valid_http_versions:
        - "HTTP/1.1"
        - "HTTP/2"
      valid_status_codes:
        - 403
      method: GET
      headers:
        User-Agent: prometheus-blackbox_exporter
        Accept-Language: en-US
      no_follow_redirects: false
      fail_if_ssl: false
      fail_if_not_ssl: false
      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: true
      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
      proxy_url: http://proxy.com:1111
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is likely due to the [config being typed incorrectly](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/issues/658). Http/2 used to be called http/2.0 and the blackbox exporter never updated the name for this so http/2 will fail.

```
      valid_http_versions:
        - "HTTP/1.1"
        - "HTTP/2.0"
```

The reason it still works on http is because http/2 will not work on insecure connections in almost all browsers. It's no longer mandatory, but [most browsers choose not to support it](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/getting-ready-for-http2/).
This is why using http it works fine since it is changed to http/1.1. You can verify this by opening the network tab in inspector mode and viewing request.